# How to attach SQL Server database file (.mdf) during creating of installation file in Visual Studio 2010 using data directory

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I developed a simple book entry system application where all the data will be saved to database file `bookdb.mdf`. When I tried to create installation file I don't know where to put my database file. Besides I need to change my connection string.

Here is my current connection string

```
{"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\\Software\\Projects\\Visual Studio project\\Seminar Library CSE KU\\bookdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"}
```

I have tried to change my connection string by adding a application configuration file to the solution and there I write

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="bookdb.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Software\Projects\Visual Studio project\Seminar Library CSE KU\bookdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True" />
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

But when I install my application to other computer it shows database file missing. So please help me how to solve this problem

Comment: Since it's a **SQL Server** file, you will also have to install SQL Server **Express** on any machine that is supposed to use your `.mdf` file

Comment: What is the path of the database when the application is installed? Somewhere in the user profile directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the database file into a subfolder of the users ApplicationData directory. The installer project will know how to place the mdf file there, and you can set up your connection string in code as follows:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename={0}\\Seminar Library CSE KU\\bookdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

#if DEBUG
    connectionString = string.Format(connectionString, "E:\\Software\\Projects\\Visual Studio project\\");
#else
    connectionString = string.Format(connectionString, Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
#endif

// Use your connection string here.
```

Comment: When i want to debug it shows an error.Here is my error report: "An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file E:\Software\Projects\Visual Studio project\\Seminar Library CSE KU\bookdb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."