# Connection string C# Entity Framework SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, installation, connection-string, advanced-installer

I am using C# WPF EF6.0 and SQL Server Express for final program.

I have created a setup file with Advanced installer that creates database via script and SQL Server Express in

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA
```

and I have changed my string connection from

```
<add name="MyDBEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyDBModel.csdl|res://*/MyDBModel.ssdl|res://*/MyDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDB.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

To this

```
<add name="MyDBEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyDBModel.csdl|
                       res://*/MyDBModel.ssdl|
                       res://*/MyDBModel.msl;
                       provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
                       provider connection string=&quot;
                             Data source=.\SQLExpress;
                             integrated security=True;
                             MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
                             Initial Catalog=MyDB;
                             App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I have installed .net Framework 4.5 and SQL Server 2012 sp1 v11.0.300 that I have used in Visual Studio 2013

When I install my program, everything works, but when I run my program it stopped working at first launch. I think the connection string has a problem.
If I click debug in Visual Studio, I see this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll.Additional information: No connection string named 'MyDBEntities' could be found in the application config file.

Comment: are you getting any error..

Comment: No just stopped working

Comment: if i click debug in visual show this error.=>An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll.Additional information: No connection string named 'MyDBEntities' could be found in the application config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I couldn't create a setup file with `Advanced Installer`.
But I created it by `Install Shield`.
My problem was insert or delete or edit from database.
I installed my program in other drive and my problem solved.
The reason was a joke that program files in `C` is `readonly`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you have not attached the database files to the local database engine. try to use the appropriate SQL Server methods which are available. Your application (after installation) can not find the database in the local DB engine.

Comment: There are different ways, one of them can be using sp_attach_db in SQL Server and writing a procedure, consider this point that this method should not be in the moving database. the cause is that you have not attached your DB so you can not use its procedures. for more information use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794.aspx

Comment: can i use attachdbfilename in my Connection string and give this location??=>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

Comment: Actually you are using installation process so it seems that you want your application to be portable so you should not use absolute path. and about the mentioned attribute I guess you should take a look at https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/

Comment: i am new in this. When i use the script inline in Advance Installer And use SQL Express its create the Database at this location. i dont understand the Complex ways

Comment: Have you included the database files to installer folders?

Comment: no i just create a script from my database in  Predefined Connection. so at install app the script work and make my database in above location

Comment: Actually I doubt it works. because I guess this process does not detach the database

Comment: now i have included myDB in the folder app and use attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDB.mdf; but i got the same error

Comment: It is logical that is not working, go to your sql server detach the database, copy files in a separate folder with enough privilege then include the db data and log files in your installation folders.

Comment: i have confused. what is the standard Way to Create a setup file. i see many tutorial videos that using the same way and its work for them. i dont understand the problem

Comment: Have they ever attached database in their installation?

Comment: Look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772846/how-to-attach-sql-server-database-file-mdf-during-creating-of-installation-fi and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16231/Deploy-your-Application-and-Database