# my database turned into a "read-only" after changing PC

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio-2017, windows-installer, project

I need Help

I recently just created a program using **Visual Studio 2017** with C#, i'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project Extension to create the installation.
i've tried installing the program in PC i used for programming (I created the database directly from Visual Studio Without sql management studio) and there's no problem there but
i faced a problem where after i Installed the program in different Computer, the Database turned into a fail

```
Failed to update database "C\... .mdf" because the database is read only.
```

i don't have sql management studio installed here as well. I've already tried to change the allowance from all the users on this PC but it still happenning.
so if you guys have any idea on what should i do that would be a lot of help.

Comment: Looks like you installed your database into a folder where the user does not have write access. Also, are you actually using MySQL? Twice you mention *SQL management stuidio*, and SQL  Server Management Studio is used for working with SQL Server and not MySQL.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20772846/4096667